# for loop : string & number without keep adding &

Tags: vb.net

I'm learning for loop and I cannot get this problem fixed.

The problems are in the following codes.

```
dim rt as integer = 2
dim i As Integer = 0
dim currentpg as string = "http://homepg.com/"


 For i = 0 To rt

currentpg = currentpg & "?pg=" & i

messagebox.show(currentpg)

next

'I hoped to get the following results

http://homepg.com/?pg=0
http://homepg.com/?pg=1
http://homepg.com/?pg=2

'but instead I'm getting this

http://homepg.com/?pg=0
http://homepg.com/?pg=0?pg=0
http://homepg.com/?pg=0?pg=0?pg=0
```

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: I noticed you have never accepted an answer. [If you ask a new question and you get an answer which works for you personally, you should accept it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) That is how you say _Thank you!_ to the user who posted it.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know. I thought pressing ^ rep up means accepting answer so I did that. Now I see there is a tick button below it Thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
Dim basepg as string = "http://homepg.com/"
For i = 0 To rt
  Dim currentpg As String = basepg & "?pg=" & i
  messagebox.show(currentpg)
Next
```

Although a proper approach would be to accumulate results into a List(Of String), and then display in a messagebox once (or a textbox/file, if too many results). You don't want to bug user for every URL (what if there are 100 of them?). They would get tired of clicking OK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you went wrong while copying the output of the buggy code. Here is the real one.

```
http://homepg.com/?pg=0
http://homepg.com/?pg=0?pg=1
http://homepg.com/?pg=0?pg=1?pg=2
```

It does not work because `currentpg` should be a **constant** but it is changed on each iteration.
Do not set, just get.

```
MessageBox.Show(currentpg & "?pg=" & i)
```

Or you can use another variable to make it more readable.

```
Dim newpg As String = currentpg & "?pg=" & i
MessageBox.Show(newpg)
```

Also, your code is inefficient. I suggest you to change it like this.

```
Dim iterations As Integer = 2
Dim prefix As String = "http://homepg.com/?pg="
For index As Integer = 0 To iterations
    MessageBox.Show(prefix & index)
Next
```